# Is it possible to share a file that stored using storage access framework with other apps

Tags: storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

I saved a document to disc using the storage access framework. Is there any way to share that particular document file with other apps using intent?

I share using the below method:

```
    fun Activity.sharePdf(pdfUri: Uri) {

    var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

        val uri =
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this,
                this.packageName.toString() + ".provider",
                File(pdfUri.toString())
            )
        intent.type = "application/pdf";
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    } else {
        intent.type = "application/pdf";
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pdfUri.toString())
        intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File")
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    }
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

This is not working with a file stored using SAF.

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me

```
fun Activity.sharePdf(pdfUri: Uri) {

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.type = "application/pdf"
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pdfUri)
intent.clipData = ClipData("fileName", arrayOf("application/pdf"), ClipData.Item(pdfUri))
   

 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "chooserTitle"))
}
```